# How to Install a Macromedia Dreamweaver using Wine

Tags: software-installation

I need to install Macromedia Dreamweaver in Ubuntu14.04. I have Wine1.6 installed in my system. I have a setup file of Macromedia Dreamweaver of Windows. Is there possible to install windows setup file directly in Ubuntu using wine? If is it possible,I need to know Installation steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend using "PlayOnLinux" if you are uncomfortable with the command line. It presents a nice GUI front-end for managing Wine virtual drives. You can either use pre-configured install scripts from the PoL team (I found one for "Dreamweaver 8" using the search bar that might work for you) or click the "Install a non-listed program" link at the bottom of the "Install" menu to use the executable you downloaded.

See also:

- [Ubuntu Help for PlayOnLinux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PlayOnLinux)
- [Ubuntu Help for Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine)
- [Wine wiki on Adobe Dreamweaver](http://wiki.winehq.org/AdobeDreamweaver)
- [Wine AppDB entry for Adobe Dreamweaver](https://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?appId=183)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, wine utility is used for installing and running Windows programs on Ubuntu. So your Dreamweaver should also install. But it is always best to install and use Ubuntu or that particular OS specific version of software because running Windows program on Wine utility doesn't work properly with full features. This has been my experience so far. So now I try to use only Ubuntu specific versions of Windows softwares. Check if Dreamweaver has any Linux/Ubuntu specific version and use that if possible.